# How to increase fonts in all UI elements in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a possibility to increase/decrease font size in all UI elements throughout the IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It's possible to override font/size for the UI in Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance | **Use custom font** (Size):

[image: override UI font]

Editor font is configured in Settings | Editor | Font.

Comment: I can see the overriden font also in the project view and trees

Comment: @mirelon, I think the answer is for an earlier version.  The font change does the right thing in 14.

Comment: It would be awesome if the answer were updated for the sake of the future readers (it changes the font everywhere, including the project vies/trees).

Comment: @CrazyCoder updating fonts works for the entire UI now (2018.1). You should update your answer.

Comment: I have recently begun using Intellij Idea.. (version 2018.2)  I cannot determine how to get to this screen... any suggestions?

Comment: @TheGeeko61 https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/accessing-settings.html, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-appearance.html

Comment: Oh!  The [Settings] from the File menu... Thanks!  I'm using Ubuntu and I think that it is undermining the Ctrl-Alt-S keystroke.

Answer (score 58):

Follow these three steps to change all fonts in the IDE (including project tree and console):

1)

Perform a search based on fonts in the settings menu:

[image]

2)

[image]

3)

[image]

Comment: Excellent, this changes the project tree and console as well.

Answer (score 17):

As of version 2020.3 the UI looks like this:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>
2. Settings:
   [image: IntelliJ Settings]

Answer (score 6):

I'm now using Intellij 2019.12.3, and the answer should be:

```
Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviors -> Appearance -> Use custom font
```

[image]

Comment: This should be top answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to have an answer to a similar question: [Is it possible to change the font size of the project panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380487/is-it-possible-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-project-panel)

You could also try changing your system font and see if Intellij picks that up. Might only work for the menus though and if you are using the system theme like GTK+ on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

For IntelliJ 2022.2 it´s pretty simple:

### For the Editor Area

Setings->Editor->General

under font-size changing with Ctrl+Mouse Wheel you can set "All editors"

### **For the UI Area**

Setings->Apperance & Behavior->Appearance

There you can direct change the Font and Size

[Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ggG.png)
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVnpJ.png)

Answer (score -1):

The simple one is:

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+A.
2. In the popup frame, type Increase font size or Decrease font size, and then click Enter.

[Doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/zooming-in-the-editor.html)

Comment: This just changes the editor font.  The question is about every other UI element in Intellij, since the default font size is absurdly tiny.

Comment: This also changes only the editor font size from the current class, not from all opened classes

Comment: This does not answer the OP question.