# How to change line space in Project window?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to change line space for Project window only in Intellij IDEA? I've seen "Overrride default fonts" in Settings which is "not recommended". Is there a recommended way to do that? Thanks.

Comment: There was not recommended settings only for specific fonts. What do you mean under 'line space' ?

Comment: The space between lines.

Comment: Project view is a tree with nodes, font line spacing doesn't control the gaps between the nodes.

Comment: @CrazyCoder, is that possible to reduce the space between nodes somehow?

Comment: No, it's not possible. Why do you need it? I don't recall anyone ever requested it.

Comment: @CrazeCoder, Just to save some space, to see more so to say :)

Comment: Submit a request: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA .

Comment: I need this too!! Having no line spacing for the editor is silly, especially when you can change the font size

Comment: @CrazyCoder please have a look at my post

Answer (score 33):

Found solution in IDEA [ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231685) (thanks for support help!):

1. Enable "[Internal Mode](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/internal_actions/enabling_internal.html#setting-internal-mode-in-the-ide-properties-file)"
2. Open "Find Action" (Ctrl-Shift-A), find "LaF Defaults" and press Enter
3. Find "Tree.rowHeight" property and change it

Value 20 is perfect for me

Comment: Thanks so much! I was suffering several weeks!

Comment: You're the boss

Comment: Just to be clear... 0 is auto... is the same that 20

Comment: Макс Ветер answer is only for Paid feature for the theme, this way works great, thank you

Comment: It works, however the value is not persisted and gets back to 28 in my case when the IDE is restarted.

Comment: ugh, this trick no longer works for me in 2021.3

Comment: This still works. You just need to go Settings > Appearance > Change font size (e.g: 13) > then apply. Change it back (e.g: 12) after you see the change in your project tree rowHeight.

Comment: Is this scriptable? I have a plugin that undoes this on every version update, and I'm keeping the plugin. Don't know about IJ scripting. Would want to change the font size to something else and back again, too, as mentioned ☝️ so that the change takes effect.

Answer (score 28):

I solved this by using Material Theme.
Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Material Theme -> Project View -> Custom Sidebar Height.

[image]

Comment: It does reduce the spaces between nodes in the Project View.

Comment: This menu item seems to be (re)moved in some later version. I can't find it on 19.3.3. Do you happen to know where it has been moved?

Comment: @MichieI Haisma, still see it in the Project view, as of 2020/07/31. Maybe it was added back?

Comment: Just perfect. Typing 10/12/14 also works in 2020.3 version. default min is 18.

Comment: Updated: The Material Theme is a paid subscription (1.5€/month) theme now. The Answer from @shooma works perfect!

Answer (score 14):

I think it's possible only for editor. You can change it using this settings panel:
[image]

Comment: That 'Line Spacing' only increase it in code editor.
Do you know how to achieve the same in project file list tab?

Comment: @mc.dev  15-yr user of Jetbrains ide's here saying : pretty sure there's no built-in way to do that. there's an answer below that changes plugin them that might do it.

Comment: Btw now there are plenty of UI plugins, so maybe there is something out there

Answer (score 2):

version: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.2

File-> Settings-> Editor-> Font-> Line spacing

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Plugin Theme, and set Tree.rowHeight and List.rowHeight to X.

Juste wrote a tutorial about it:
https://medium.com/@let92/set-line-height-in-project-view-of-jetbrains-ide-36c07de3254

Answer (score 1):

LaF Default solution of @shooma is still working.

Here are the steps:
First Three steps is still the same as @shooma's solution but need further steps to apply your changes.

1. Enable "Internal Mode"
2. Open "Find Action" (Ctrl-Shift-A), find "LaF Defaults" and press
   Enter
3. Find "Tree.rowHeight" property and change it

Here are the next new steps

1. Go to Settings > Appearance
2. Change Font Size to anything (e.g: 13)
3. Apply ( you should be able to see the difference, you can try rowHeight 40 to see big difference )
4. -optional- Change it back to your Font Size (you may not need this step if you are satisfied with your current font size)