# Increase line spacing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I would like to increase the space between the lines of code in visual studio (to help me get less distracted while reading the code). I know this is possible in IntelliJ/Rider (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17808746)). Is there a similar setting or option in VS?

I have searched and the only option I can find is to make the space between the lines smaller using the PPT extension.
Another option that I read somewhere (but can't find anymore) was to create a custom font with taller characters.

Comment: I did find the post again to create a custom font, so I will try this now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18084478/10717433

Comment: It does work but it's more hassle than I would like, if anyone does have a better solution/extension I would love to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on VS 2015/2017/2019 (this extension doesn't support VS 2022), you can use the [LinePress](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=OmarRwemi.LinePress) extension available on the VS Marketplace.

[image: LinePress in action]

Setting it up is really easy, after installing it, go to the Tools menu > Options > LinePress, you can set there the line height at your liking. (You can also set up  the height of empty lines and compress lines with specific contents.)
[image: LinePress settings]

#### BONUS: Support for VS 2022

There's an integrated option into the Settings, just go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > General and on the right pane find the option Line spacing, and set its value to one of your liking.
[image: Setting line height on VS 2022]