# Enlarge font for project view in AppCode

Tags: fonts, jetbrains-ide, appcode

I know how to enlarge the font of code in the editor but how can I enlarge the font for the project view.

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380487/is-it-possible-to-change-the-font-size-of-the-project-panel) but it is addressing IntelliJ and not AppCode. When I go to `Appearance` under `Settings`, I do not see any options to change the Project View font size.

## Edit:

people say go to settings/appearance, but this is what i see..
[image]

Comment: *"When I go to Appearance under Settings, I do not see any options to change the Project View font size."* That's because there is none that would target Project View only. Please show a screenshot of what options do you see there.

Answer (score 0):

Try Settings->Appearance->Override default fonts by->Below choose new font

[image]

Comment: by "Settings" do you mean "File -> Default Settings"?  and under there I only see "Appearance and Behavior" which contains "Fill Colors" and "Scopes".

Comment: added screenshot